# about the derivative of the Heaviside step function

Tags: functions, dirac-delta, step-function

I know that the derivative of the Heaviside step function follows:

$${\partial  \over {\partial {t_1}}}\theta \left( {{t_1} - {t_2}} \right) = \delta \left( {{t_1} - {t_2}} \right)$$

what about if the derivation with respect to t2? as follows:

$${\partial  \over {\partial {t_2}}}\theta \left( {{t_1} - {t_2}} \right) = ??$$

Edit:
I found the answer in

> Kokhanovsky, Alexander A. Light scattering reviews 3: light scattering
> and reflection. Springer Science & Business Media, 2008

Equation (A.22):
$${\partial  \over {\partial {t_2}}}\theta \left( {{t_1} - {t_2}} \right) =  - \delta \left( {{t_2} - {t_1}} \right)$$
and because of the Dirac delta function is even, we can set:
$${\partial  \over {\partial {t_2}}}\theta \left( {{t_1} - {t_2}} \right) =  - \delta \left( {{t_1} - {t_2}} \right)$$

Comment: Use the definition of the weak derivative.

Comment: @Deane Does it simply equal the negative of the previous case? 
$$ - \delta \left( {{t_1} - {t_2}} \right)$$

Comment: Show us your calculation that shows this. What’s important is not the answer but making sure you know how answer questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can justify that
$$
{\mathrm{d}\over\mathrm{d} t}\theta(t) = \delta(t)
$$
in some sense (not gonna open that can of worms), we can define $t=t_1 - t_2$ and use the chain rule to show that
$$
{\partial\over\partial t_1}\theta(t) = {\mathrm{d}\theta\over\mathrm{d}t}{\partial t\over\partial t_1} = \delta(t) = \delta(t_1 - t_2)
$$
and
$$
{\partial\over\partial t_2}\theta(t) = {\mathrm{d}\theta\over\mathrm{d}t}{\partial t\over\partial t_2} = -\delta(t) = -\delta(t_1 - t_2).
$$